# next-auth FirestoreAdapter not connecting to backend

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to implement the next-auth to authenticate and store user details through #GoogleProvider.

For some reason, the app is not connecting to the backend. I changed the firestore security rules to all, but the problem remains.

**[...nextauth].js**

```
import { FirestoreAdapter } from '@next-auth/firebase-adapter';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import { app, db } from '../../../config/firebase';

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  adapter: FirestoreAdapter({
    apiKey: '...',
    authDomain: '...',
    projectId: '...',
    storageBucket: '...',
    databaseURL: '...',
    messagingSenderId: '...',
    appId: '...',
  }),
  debug: true,
});
```

**firebase.js**

```
import { initializeApp, getApp, getApps } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { initializeFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '...',
  authDomain: '...',
  projectId: '...',
  storageBucket: '...',
  messagingSenderId: '...',
  appId: '...',
  measurementId: '...',
};


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export { app, auth, db };
```

**firestore security rules **

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

**Error**

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.12.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Permission denied: Consumer 'project:undefined' has been suspended.

Comment: can you please check this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67845455/could-not-reach-cloud-firestore-backend-connection-failed-1-times) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71045643/could-not-reach-cloud-firestore-backend-react-native-firebase-v9)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your projectId is defined in your firebase config?
I had the same problem because my projectId value was not defined in my .env file so process.env.PROJECT_ID returned 'undefined'

try to log firebaseConfig and check if everything's good

Comment: Thanks, found a typo where I referenced to projecID wrongly and of course it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To allow browsers to access environment variables, different frameworks require distinct prefixes for these variables.

If you are using the **Next.js framework**, the environment variable names should be prefixed with "**NEXT_PUBLIC_**". ([Configuring: Environment Variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables))

If you are using the **Create React App framework**, the environment variable names should be prefixed with "**REACT_APP_**". ([Adding Custom Environment Variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/))